# How to generate a documentation from ansible-modules

Tags: ansible, documentation

We are developing an ansible collection using ansible modules like openstack does: https://github.com/openstack/ansible-collections-openstack

How can I generate docs from the modules like the ansible wiki has it? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/os_auth_module.html#os-auth-module

I found this on the internet but I can't get antsibull to work
https://www.die-welt.net/2020/07/building-documentation-for-ansible-collections-using-antsibull/
The problem there is that despite of having the ANSIBLE_COLLECTIONS_PATH env var set it will just output an nearly empty file with `antsibull-docs collection --use-current --dest-dir ~/docs collectionname`

Also I don't know whether this is the right way to do that.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the documents(rst) for the self-made collection using antsibull-docs.
The following is the procedure for generating the documents.

1. ansible installation

Install ansible.

```
pip install ansible-base
ansible --version
ansible 2.10.5
```

2. antsibull installation

Clone the antsibull repo and install.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
git clone https://github.com/ansible-community/antsibull.git
cd antsibull/
pip install poetry
poetry install
cd ..
```

3. create collections directory

This time, create a collections directory in the current(working) directory.
Change the namespace based on self-made collections.

```
mkdir -p collections/ansible_collections/{namespace}/
```

4. move your collection into the namespace directory

```
mv {your_collection} collections/ansible_collections/{namespace}/
```

5. ansible.cfg creation

Create an ansible.cfg to specify the collection directory path.

```
vi ansible.cfg
```

```
[defaults]
COLLECTIONS_PATHS = {your_working_directory_path}/collections
```

Check the config is reflected.

```
ansible-config dump --only-changed
COLLECTIONS_PATHS({your_working_directory_path}/ansible.cfg) = ['{your_working_directory_path}/collections']
```

Check a module document can be seeing with ansible-doc.

```
ansible-doc namespace.your_collection.module_name
```

6. generate .rst files for the module

```
mkdir -p build/plugin_docs
antsibull-docs collection --use-current --squash-hierarchy --dest-dir ./build/plugin_docs namespace.your_collection
ls ./build/plugin_docs
```

With this, the module .rst documents are generated in build/plugin_docs directory.
If a build error occurs, check that there aren't the parameters wrong in galaxy.yml in your_collection directory.

Comment: Hey @sky_jokerxx
I've tried the ansible.cfg thing and ansible-doc namespace.your_collection.module_name also shows me the correct module. The problem is that antsibull still only outputs a empty index.rst.

When installing the collection via ansible-galaxy in the ~/.ansible path it works however. So what am I doing wrong?

The config dump specifies the correct path

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the cause of the blank index.rst. There mey be the cause in the jinja2 template. It a processing code for generating index.rst of jinja2 template is https://github.com/ansible-community/antsibull/blob/c886f715c671557e0ffcab75dab265763f89b762/antsibull/write_docs.py#L320-L343

Comment: @sky_jokerxx, my collection has certain modules that are inside directories so they would look like my_namespace.my_collection.my_dir.module_1 when used in a playbook. antsibull-docs does not seem to build docs for these modules, it only builds .rst files for the module files at the root level i.e. the ones right under my_namespace.my_collection\. Any idea how to create modules which are placed inside directories within the plugins\modules ?